# Preventing resolution breaking when playing a game fullscreen

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, 4k-resolution

I am sorry if the title sounds misleading, I'm not entirely sure how to best word this. I have a 3840x2160p monitor. When I play demanding games I usually have to play at a lower resolution. However I also want to play fullscreen otherwise the game will be confined to a small window, but then it breaks the resolution of the desktop and of the second screen, moving all the open windows in odd places...

Is there a way to play fullscreen at lower resolution without impacting either the second monitor or other windows size and position? Failing that, maybe a way to play in borderless fullscreen at lower resolution?

Comment: Screens should be able to resize alternate resolutions without issue. The fact yours doesn't means there's something else going on here, likely, which means we have to have more information. How are you setting the resolution in these games?

Comment: Well it resizes correctly, but when it does it breaks the layout of open windows on the second monitor no matter what (it looks like the second monitor also resizes to the lower resolution before going back to its original resolution). I'm not doing anything particular in those games, just set them to fullscreen and select a resolution lower than 2160p (usually 1440p).